# Proving that the circumcenters are concyclic.

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I was completely lost when handed this at a math competition a couple of weeks ago.

> In triangle $ABC$, medians $AA_0$, $BB_0$ and $CC_0$ intersect at a point $M$.  Prove that the circumcenters of triangles $MA_0B_0$, $MCB_0$, $MA_0C_0$, $MBC_0$ and point $M$ are concyclic.

I drew the diagram and was able to make sense of the question. My diagram also seemed to show that the circumcenters were concyclic however, because of my lack of any major exposure to circle geometry I was not able to make much progress beyond this.  Please help. I am trying to practice for the next competition.

I really appreciate your support. Thank you.

Comment: These circumcentres lie on the [van Lamoen circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Lamoen_circle).

Comment: Here is another Six Concyclic Circumcenter : https://commons.hostos.cuny.edu/mtrj/wp-content/uploads/sites/30/2022/04/v14n1-Problem-Corner.pdf.